# PySerial reading hex values

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, pyserial

I am using Python 3.12 and Pyserial 3.5. I am trying to read a hex response from a device.

I expect to get b'\x1F\xA0\x26' which is what I get when I use a RealTerm or another COM tool.

With Python I get b'x1f\n'

And if I try converting it with binascii.hexlify() or with .hex() I get b'1F0A'

```
import binascii
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM4',baudrate=9600,bytesize=8,parity="N",stopbits=1,timeout=1)

print(ser.name)

packet = b"\x1F"
ser.write(packet)

response = ser.read_until(size=3)

print(response)

print(response.hex())

print(binascii.hexlify(response))
```

Response:
COM4

b'\x1f\n'

1f0a

b'1f0a'

I think I am losing data in translation somehow and I'm not sure where/how or how to fix it.

Comment: What if you extend the timeout ? I can also see a \n in the response, and read_until stops reading at \n by default: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read_until

Comment: Does your device echo what you send it before replying?

Comment: Looks like read_until was the issue. Swapped it out with a read and got b'\x1f\n&' which converted to the correct b'1f0a26'

Comment: It was the: `"I expect to get b'\x1F\xA0\x26' "` which fooled us.